# Bacbone Marionette how to get access to an element in which the view is wrapped up?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, collectionview

I have CollectionView which has tagName and Id/tagClass. I heed apply plugin to 'tagName' element on `onRender` event. I can't access it through this.el.

```
var ListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName:'article',
    className:'myClass',
    id:'myID',
    childView: ListItemView,
    onRender: function () {

        (access to view tagName el).readmore({
            speed: 500
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you want `this.$el.readmore()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way most third-party plugins work (especially jQuery plugins), is that the element they operate on must be attached to the DOM.

So you have to do something like:

```
var listView = new ListView();
$someElement.append(listView.render().el); // Your view is in the DOM now
listView.attachPlugins();                  // And you can attach plugins
```

Where `attachPlugins` would be something like:

```
attachPlugins: function () {
  this.$el.readmore({
            speed: 500
        });
}
```